# My site not Connecting with Google Cloud Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, platform

I want to connect Google Cloud Platform Hosting to my Domain and Have tried everything.

I installed Wordpress from the Marketplace, then enabled Google Cloud DNS API, then also Cloud DNS from Network Services, and also changed the dns name from my domain name provider but my domain name does not open.

When I put my URL in the search bar, I see API request and CPU usage - https://prnt.sc/n7d5av . But My site does not open. It shows this - http://prnt.sc/n7d601

Please help me, I am stuck from past 12 hours and now my head feels like it will burst out. I did the exact process five times and nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty much like the firewall is blocking your port 80.

Make sure you add a firewall rule allowing to access your particular IP to everyone as it is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls).

[This other documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/) of Bitnami is quite clear as well.